# Solr query issue with Faceting and Stats in dse

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, solrj, solr4

Query : `http://localhost:8983/solr/trackfleet_db.location/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.pivot={!stats=piv1}date,latitude,longitude&stats=true&stats.field={!tag=piv1}gpsdt`

When I execute this query on a separate solr instance (which is not an instance of DSE) then this query works fine.

But in case of dse (Now I am using in built Solr of DSE) then it does not return anything ....And when I execute this query using curl command then it is giving following error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">400</int>
        <int name="QTime">3</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="error">
        <lst name="metadata">
            <str name="error-class">
                org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
            </str>
            <str name="root-error-class">
                org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
            </str>
        </lst>
        <str name="msg">
            undefined field: "!tag=piv1gpsdt"
        </str>
        <int name="code">400</int>
    </lst>
</response>
```

Comment: what version of DSE are you using? I think that stats may not be supported in DSE Search

Comment: I am using 5.1.7

Comment: When I am executing same query on solr-7.2.1 which is installed independently(without DSE) then it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Datastax DSE 5.1 search support Solr local paramater as used in facet.pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503266/does-datastax-dse-5-1-search-support-solr-local-paramater-as-used-in-facet-pivot)

Comment: please see the answer from DataStax's Search product manager in the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503266/does-datastax-dse-5-1-search-support-solr-local-paramater-as-used-in-facet-pivot