# stats component not working with facet pivots in solr 6.1 with DSE 5.1

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise, solr4, solrcloud

I am not able to calculate min and max for each group in solr 6.1(with DSE version 5.1)
My group columns are : date, latitude,longitude 
And I want to get min , max value of gpsdt column for each group.

I successfully can perform this operation in solr 7.1(Which is installed on a separate machine without DSE)
But when I am using Solr version 6.1(in built in DSE 5.1) then It does not work.

My query is :

http://localhost:8983/solr/location/select?q=latitude:28.183207&facet=true&facet.pivot={!stats=piv1}date,latitude,longitude&stats=true&stats.field={!tag=piv1}gpsdt&rows=100000

Please help me ...Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr query issue with Faceting and Stats in dse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320539/solr-query-issue-with-faceting-and-stats-in-dse)

Comment: Functionality of Solr in DSE is limited in some areas - please refer to official documentation to find differences between them.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48930856/1810373